# Problem with robot_localization transforms

Tags: ros, navigation, transforms, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey!

I am experimenting with robot_localization and amcl. I use a simulated turtlebot 3 which is in the `/robot1/` namespace and has  `robot1_tf` as tf-prefix.

I use  a robot_localization ekf for the `robot1_tf/odom` frame and a separate one for the map. The problem here is that this map ekf always uses `robot1_tf/map` as map frame. But I need `map` as map-frame. I tried various combinations but that didn't change it.

My launch file looks like that:

```
<group ns=robot1">
    <param name="tf_prefix" value="robot1_tf" />

    <node pkg="robot_localization" type="ekf_localization_node" name="ekf_se_odom" clear_params="true">
          <rosparam command="load" file="$(find tb3_lidar_navigation)/params/odom_ekf.yaml" />
    </node>
  
    <node pkg="robot_localization" type="ekf_localization_node" name="ekf_se_map" clear_params="true">
      <remap from="odometry/filtered" to="odometry/filtered_map"/>
      <rosparam command="load" file="$(find tb3_lidar_navigation)/params/map_ekf.yaml" />
    </node>

    <!--- Run AMCL -->
    <include file="$(find tb3_lidar_navigation)/launch/amcl.launch.xml">
          <arg name="robot_ns"       value="$(arg robot_ns)"/>
          <arg name="robot_tf"       value="$(arg robot_tf)"/>
          <arg name="initial_pose_x" value="$(arg initial_pose_x)"/>
          <arg name="initial_pose_y" value="$(arg initial_pose_y)"/>
          <arg name="initial_pose_a" value="$(arg initial_pose_a)"/>
          <arg name="tf_broadcast"   value="false"/>
    </include>
  </group>
```

The config file for the map_ekf looks like that:

```
frequency: 30
sensor_timeout: 0.1
two_d_mode: true
transform_time_offset: 0.0
transform_timeout: 0.0
print_diagnostics: true
debug: false    

map_frame: map
odom_frame: odom
base_link_frame: base_footprint
world_frame: map

odom0: odom
odom0_config: [false, false, false,
               false, false, false,
               true,  true,  true,
               false, false, true,
               false, false, false]
odom0_queue_size: 10
odom0_nodelay: true
odom0_differential: false
odom0_relative: false

pose0: amcl_pose
pose0_config: [true,  true,  false,
               false, false, false,
               false, false, false,
               false, false, false,
               false, false, false]
pose0_queue_size: 10
pose0_nodelay: true
pose0_differential: false
pose0_relative: false

imu0: imu
imu0_config: [false, false, false,
              true,  true,  false,
              false, false, false,
              true,  true,  true,
              true,  true,  true]
imu0_nodelay: true
imu0_differential: false
imu0_relative: false
imu0_queue_size: 10
imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: true

use_control: false
```

Does anybody know how I can change the map frame?
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274763/problem-with-robot_localization-transforms/) by [jauer](https://answers.ros.org/users/32456/jauer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-11-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ufr3c_tjc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28584/ufr3c_tjc/) on 2017-11-01**:
Try with a forward slash in front, to tell the node that it is an absolute name: `/map`.

**Comment by [jauer](https://answers.ros.org/users/32456/jauer/) on 2017-11-02**:
Thank you! I already tried that and it resulted in the same tf-tree as without slash. So this is no solution.

**Comment by [ufr3c_tjc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28584/ufr3c_tjc/) on 2017-11-02**:
Maybe remove the `tf_prefix` parameter and put the frames as `robot1_tf/odom` and `map` into the YAML?

**Comment by [jauer](https://answers.ros.org/users/32456/jauer/) on 2017-11-03**:
Same again. Is it possible that the filter somehow also uses the frames which are used in the subscribed sensor topics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have `tf_prefix` set. Simply removing it from your launch file might not help, unless you start a new ROS master afterwards, or manually delete the `tf_prefix` parameter. I would stop your ROS master, remove `tf_prefix`, then run everything *without* AMCL, and check the frames. The only things that affect the EKF's use of frames are the parameters you give it and `tf_prefix`, so if it's publishing transforms in the wrong namespace, it's one of those two things.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2018-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0